# C++ Defining Struct with Template

Tags: c++, templates, struct

I don't understand why I can't define this struct:

```
//Class.h

template <class T>
struct Callback {
    T* Object;
    std::function<void()> Function;
};

template <class T>
struct KeyCodeStruct {
    typedef std::unordered_map<SDL_Keycode, Callback<T>> KeyCode;
};

template <class T>
struct BindingStruct{
    typedef std::unordered_map<int, KeyCodeStruct<T>> Binding;
};


class Class {
public:
    template <class T>
    void bindInput(SDL_EventType eventType, SDL_Keycode key, Callback<T> f);
private:
    template <class T>
    BindingStruct<T> inputBindings; //How do I define this? This gives me an error.
}
```

It gives the error:
`Member 'inputBindings' declared as a template.` 
I don't know templates very well so I probably just missed the information I need.

**Update** (In response to deviantfan)

Now my cpp class is running into issues for a function I have.

```
template <class T>
void InputManager::bindInput(SDL_EventType eventType, SDL_Keycode key, Callback<T> f)
{
    inputBindings[eventType][key] = f;
}
```

It says expected class or namespace.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Wrong:

```
class Class {
private:
    template <class T>
    BindingStruct<T> inputBindings;
}
```

Right:

```
template <class T>
class Class {
private:
    BindingStruct<T> inputBindings;
}
```

Comment: Please post the full error message, and in which line it occurs.

Comment: @TrevorPeyton That looks like a different question altogether.

Comment: @juanchopanza I was trying to keep the source code at a minimum. I didn't think those would be effected by his post.

Comment: @TrevorPeyton So what? You asked one question, you got the answer, not you are asking another one.

Comment: @juanchopanza Well if the answer causes error I don't really see that as answering the question.

Comment: @TrevorPeyton It answers the question you asked. Are you going to keep posting changes to the question each time a new compiler error pops up?

Comment: @juanchopanza So do you propose I post a new question with nearly all the same content of this question or delete this question removing all the credit that these people put into answering it?

Comment: @TrevorPeyton: I answered what you asked, and while writing the answer, I didn´t know that you´re unable to handle the rest of your code. So... maybe you should read the template chapter of a C++ book.

Comment: @TrevorPeyton No, learn to ask clear questions about one thing only. It is not rocket science.

Comment: @TrevorPeyton: You can´t delete this question anymore.

Answer (score 4):

In response to your update

If you are defining your class as a class template like so:

```
template <class T>
class InputManager
{
    ...
};
```

Then in your definition you need to show your `InputManager` is an instantiation with the type `T`:

```
template <class T>
void InputManager<T>::bindInput(SDL_EventType eventType, SDL_Keycode key, Callback<T> f)
{
    inputBindings[eventType][key] = f;
}
```

ie: Note the `InputManager<T>` rather than just `InputManager`

Comment: Alright, I assume I will have to add either a template to every method for InputManager now? Also, in places where I use InputManager what should I put as the class? InputManager<Class>? It works but seems over complicated for just putting a template on a single struct.

Comment: Then what do you want? If you really need a templated class, you´ve to specify the type when you use it. If you think that this is more complicated (because the type should be "Class"), then why a template?

Comment: @TrevorPeyton this is just how templates work. The issue you have is that `Class` is not a concrete type - it's a *class template* - it doesn't become a concrete type until you instantiate it with a template parameter, eg: `Class<MyType>`; therefore you need to instantiate the `InputManager` class template with this concrete type; so it becomes `InputManager<Class<MyType>>`